# How to add google Map marker from SQL database

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a google map and I would like to add a new marker on it for each element I add on my database (with it latitude and longitude).
This is what I have done that isn't working.
Thanks for helping.

```
<?php
    $reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM zdou ORDER BY id ');
    while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch()){

    ?>
        <p>
            <strong>latitude</strong> : <?php echo $donnees['latitude']; ?><br/>
            <strong>longitude</strong> : <?php echo $donnees['longitude']; ?><br/>
        </p>
        <?php
            $latitude = $donnees['latitude'];
            $longitude = $donnees['longitude'];
        ?>
        <script>
            latitude = <?php echo $latitude ?>;
            longitude = <?php echo $longitude ?>;
            marker = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            var placerMarker = new google.maps.Marker({position:marker,map:map,title:"Zdou"});
        </script>
        <?php
    }
    $reponse->closeCursor();
        ?>
```

And I have created the map with the user position like this :

```
function showPosition(position) {
            lat = position.coords.latitude;
            lon = position.coords.longitude;
            latlon = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon)
            mapholder = document.getElementById('mapholder')
            mapholder.style.height = '250px';
            mapholder.style.width = '500px';

            var myOptions = {
            center:latlon,zoom:12,
            mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            mapTypeControl:false,
            navigationControlOptions:{style:google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL}
            }
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapholder"), myOptions);
            var myPos = new google.maps.Marker({position:latlon,map:map,title:"You are here!"});

        }
```

**EDIT :**
I created a variable that increment each time it enter into the "script" in the while loop, and then display that variable.
Guess what, the variable is undefined, so the script in the loop isn't read.
Still need some help pls !

Answer (score 0):

Try making your map variable global. Because it is not defined when you are creating markers in the php loop.

```
var map;
function showPosition(position) {
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    lon = position.coords.longitude;
    latlon = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon)
    mapholder = document.getElementById('mapholder')
    mapholder.style.height = '250px';
    mapholder.style.width = '500px';

    var myOptions = {
    center:latlon,zoom:12,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl:false,
    navigationControlOptions:{style:google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL}
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapholder"), myOptions);
    var myPos = new google.maps.Marker({position:latlon,map:map,title:"You are here!"});

}
```

Look at this as well https://wrightshq.com/playground/placing-multiple-markers-on-a-google-map-using-api-3/

Comment: It didn't solve that problem, markers still not there. But it solved another problem with my database.
I'll now try to understand your link, thanks anyway